# Acrescentar novos valores a uma variável Linq já preenchida

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Fiz essa Lambda/Linq:

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
                p => p.CategoryId,
                c => c.Id,
                (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
                (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
                {
                    CategoryId = final.Product.CategoryId,
                    CategoryName = (c != null ? c.Name : null),
                    PictureId = final.Product.PictureId,
                    Description = final.Product.Description,
                    ShortDescription = final.Product.ShortDescription,
                    Name = final.Product.Name,
                    NameHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(final.Product.NameHtml) ? final.Product.Name : final.Product.NameHtml,
                    PartNumber = final.Product.PartNumber,
                    Hidden = final.Product.Hidden,
                    Order = final.Product.Order,
                    HaveMaximumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage,
                    MaximumPercentage = final.Product.MaximumPercentage,
                    HaveMinimumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage,
                    MinimumPercentage = final.Product.MinimumPercentage,
                    AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
                    AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
                    StandardMarkup = final.Product.StandardMarkup

                }).ToList();
```

Fiz isso para substituir um Foreach, que a cada passada estava indo ao banco, quebrando a performance. Antes eu tinha o código abaixo dentro do Foreach e que não consegui colocar dentro da expressão acima(**qry**):

```
if (product.PictureId.HasValue)
            item.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;

        var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);

        item.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);

        var price = await _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId);
        if (product.PriceType == ProductPriceType.Dolar)
        {
            if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                item.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;
        }

        item.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
        item.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
        item.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
        item.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;
```

**item** era uma variável dentro do foreach do tipo **CatalogItemResponse**. Bem, preciso agora carregar esses valores, nas condições acima para dentro da var **qry** para quando eu fizer os comandos abaixo, esses valores já serão carregados na tela

```
var model = new CatalogResponse();
model.CatalogDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
model.Items = new List<CatalogItemResponse>( qry );
return Ok(model);
```

Como eu faço isso? É necessário um foreach do tipo:

```
qry.ForEach(q => q.meu_campo_aqui_nas_condições....)?
```

***OBS: product era a variável do Foreach, que percorria uma lista products.***

**EDIT**

Fi isso na atribuição:

```
qry.ForEach(q => {
     var product = new Product();
     var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId);
     if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
           q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;
});
```

Mas **price** não possui **BasePriceUSD** e os demais

Deu certo assim(com async):

```
qry.ForEach(async q => {
                var product = new Product();
                var price = await _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId);
                if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                    q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;
            });
```

**EDIT2**

Fazendo isso?

```
qry.ForEach(async q => {
                var product = new Product();
                var price = await _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId);
                if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                    q.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                q.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                q.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                q.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;

            });
```

Os valores continuam vindo 0.00. Acredito que o new Product(), possa ter matado. Antes eu tinha uma service que dava um GetAll() em Product. Eu matei ela, pois trazia tudo(GetAll()). Vou colocar de volta no lugar de new Product() e ver se consigo retornar os valores de R$ e Dollar.

Comment: Não entendi o down vote acima, já que a pergunta permite uma resposta apenas, ou seja, como atribuir valores a uma var lambda já preenchida

Comment: eu estou até acostumado com esse tipo de coisa... deve ter alguns cidadãos que nasceram para dar down vote ou pedir para fechar perguntas que estão dentro das regras.

Comment: Falta é moderação para isso. Eu tive algumas discussões aqui. Um cara levou para o lado profissional e sempre me responde bem, mas tem outro(s) que não importa a pergunta, se é minha, levo downvote de cara.

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida? Como armazenar  o `price` pra dentro da sua query?

Comment: Isso mesmo, o price no foreach anterior vinha de uma service, como visto no código. Como estava dentro de um foreach, eu passava a var(var do foreach) **product**, a quantidade 1 e o ID da revenda ou usuário.

Comment: Tentei isso: `qry.ForEach(q => q.ResellerPriceUSD = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(??????, 1, resellerId));`, mas onde está a interrogação, se espera um Product e a var lambda q não é um produto. Não sei o q faer

Comment: Não me parece muito prático... da forma como está você teria que requisitar o método para cada propriedade

Comment: Não é o caso de usar uma stored procedure?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, o sistema já funciona. Só tenho que melhorar a performance dele, esse é meu trabalho.